# How to access ASP session variables from native IIS HTTP module

Tags: c++, winapi, iis, session-variables, httpmodule

I'm writing a native C++ IIS HTTP module, the kind that starts with the RegisterModule() function.  I'd like to access the ASP session variables, but I don't see anything in httpserv.h that seems "Session" related.

I found an old page where someone says it isn't possible to get the ASP session object from an ISAPI module, but I'm hoping it's now possible to access the session variables from an IIS HTTP module using native C++.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/069881c0-160e-4169-8c3d-e551e860fcdc/iis7-c-module-to-get-asp-session

I have objects of type IHttpContext and IHttpRequest.  Does anyone know how I can access the ASP session variables?

Thanks!

Comment: ASP "classic" hasn't changed since, so no, it's still not possible.